# users list - show users that created in system

Tags: users

I want a ***command in terminal*** thats show me wich 'users' are created,
I use the `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd`
and seen all users include system users and additional users, i want list of the users that created and added to system.

Comment: please clarify the difference in what `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd` provides and what you actually want

Answer (score 3):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $3 <=59999 {print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

It only lists users with the user ID greater than 1000 and less than 59999, which is what you are looking for. these numbers are first to last inclusive range of UIDs which will be assigned dynamically to user accounts/groups.

To see where the `1000` and `59999` comes from, look at `/etc/adduser.conf`:

```
grep -e '^FIRST_UID' -e '^LAST_UID' /etc/adduser.conf
```